# Impute missing value by estimating the equation from non missing value in pandas and scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Price        Category      Area
20           Red           100
30           Red           150
10           Red           50
25           Red           NaN
30           Red           NaN
10           Green         30
20           Green         60
30           Green         90
10           Green         30
40           Green         NaN
50           Green         NaN
```

From the above, I would like to estimate the relation between Area and Price separately for each category Red and Green.

For example here for Red:

```
Area = 5 * Price
```

Similarly for Green:

```
Area = 3 * Price
```

I would like to implement that into pandas and scikit-learn:

Steps
1. Estimate the relation between Area and Price for each category.
2. Based on the relation impute the missing values.

I am very new in python and coding.

```
Expected output
Price        Category      Area
20           Red           100
30           Red           150
10           Red           50
25           Red           125
30           Red           150
10           Green         30
20           Green         60
30           Green         90
10           Green         30
40           Green         120
50           Green         150
```

Comment: how are you saving the factors for red and green?

Comment: @anky_91 I am not sure, Actually I don't how to solve this problem by coding.. Can we filter the data frame for each category and estimate the factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use a dictionary as below and then stack and fillna:

```
d={'Area_Red' : 5 * df['Price'] , 'Area_Green' : 3 * df['Price']}
df_ref=pd.DataFrame(d).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[1]).stack()
df['Area']=df.set_index('Category',append=True)['Area'].fillna(df_ref).droplevel(1)
```

Incase you want to just get the values as per `df_ref` and update the `Area` col (not just fillna), change the last line to below, use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
d={'Area_Red' : 5 * df['Price'] , 'Area_Green' : 3 * df['Price']}
df_ref=pd.DataFrame(d).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[1]) #without stack
df['Area']=df_ref.lookup(df['Category'].index,df['Category'])
```

---

```
print(df)

    Price Category  Area
0      20      Red   100
1      30      Red   150
2      10      Red    50
3      25      Red   125
4      30      Red   150
5      10    Green    30
6      20    Green    60
7      30    Green    90
8      10    Green    30
9      40    Green   120
10     50    Green   150
```

Comment: @anky_91 is it possible to estimate that  regression coefficient in non missing values.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with:

1. Getting the factors with `Area / Price`
2. `GroupBy` on `Category`
3. Filling up `NaN` with `ffill` and `bfill`
4. Multiplying `Price` with the new factors to create new `Area` column

```
df['factors'] = df['Area'] / df['Price']
df['factors'] = df.groupby('Category', sort=False)['factors'].ffill().bfill()

df = df.assign(Area=df['Price'] * df['factors']).drop(columns='factors')
```

```
    Price Category  Area
0      20      Red 100.0
1      30      Red 150.0
2      10      Red  50.0
3      25      Red 125.0
4      30      Red 150.0
5      10    Green  30.0
6      20    Green  60.0
7      30    Green  90.0
8      10    Green  30.0
9      40    Green 120.0
10     50    Green 150.0
```